# SDK is not defined for Run Configuration

Tags: python, pycharm

When I'm trying to run my project in PyCharm I'm getting an error:

> SDK is not defined for Run Configuration.

I tried to set a new interpreter and tried everything.

What does "SDK" mean and where can I configure it?

[image: error popup on run button]

Comment: If one of the answers below worked for you, consider accepting it as the answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just had this same issue (see my comment above). What worked for me was to go into "Edit Configurations", delete the configuration that was copied over from the original PC, and create my own configuration (basically with the same inputs as before).

Answer (score 8):

This might happen if a run configuration was imported from another computer.

Run configuration can contain a path to a Python interpreter from that computer.

By default, run configurations are stored in `.idea/runConfigurations/*.xml`.

If you pull up `.idea/runConfigurations/<your-configuration>.xml` you'll probably notice a fixed path to the Python interpreter somewhere in there, e.g.:

```xml
<option name="SDK_HOME" value="$USER_HOME$/.local/share/virtualenvs/your-project-name-XXXXXXXX/bin/python" />
```

alongside with

```xml
<option name="IS_MODULE_SDK" value="false" />
```

It that's true try changing those lines to

```xml
<option name="SDK_HOME" value="" />
<option name="IS_MODULE_SDK" value="true" />
```

This will make your IntelliJ IDE look for Python in your local project's virtual environment folder.

---

Basically, like folks have already mentioned before, simple recreation of your run configuration by hand will help because it will disregard other machine's settings and apply yours, but sometimes it may cumbersome (especially, if your run configuration contains some project-specific environment variables and other stuff which can be tedious to copy over).

So, just changing those two lines in the run configuration XML file should help without recreating it manually again from scratch.

The nastiest thing about this situation with Python path is that when you import a run configuration for a Python project from another machine with Python path being hardcoded PyCharm will still keep showing you yours in the Edit Configurations window making it really hard to track down and fix, so in this very specific case don't believe what you see in the run configuration UI -- just go and check the run configuration XML config behind.

Answer (score 1):

The IDE itself proposed to make recently created venv as interpreter, I agreed and after that this mistake occured. The decision: I came to the run->edit configurations and I saw that  interpreter path wasn't setted. Than I've added the path by myself and everything worked

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem,and I have solved it.
You need to open Run/Debug Configurations of Pycharm.
Then find Parameters of your py file, Copy and delete the parameters, and then fill in the parameters as they are

Answer (score -1):

Go to `Edit Configuration` and uncheck the `Add source root to PYTHONPATH` option:

[image]

Comment: A variation of this solution worked for me. Not sure what happened but on MacOS, an OS update broke my run configuration. Unchecking that box and then rechecking it fixed my issue

Answer (score -2):

It is just because you have not setup your Python interpreter properly.

Just try this and also make sure you are using Virtual environment-

`Run/Debug Configurations -> Check for the correct python interpreter and working directory`

then close project and restart Pycharm.

Answer (score -3):

Quick fix: Copy and paste the project, then run the copy.

This issue has occurred for me a few times when running Scripts that others have created.